# How to set env variables when compiling Node on Windows, from Mingw32?

Tags: windows, git, variables, node.js, environment

I'm following the instructions from various Wikis on how to compile Node so I can eventually get it running as a service on Windows.

My steps so far:

1. https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation
   (which lead to...)
2. http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/03/16/node-js-on-windows/
   (successfully compiled via cygwin, but lead to...)
3. https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-mingw
   (which apparently is better than the so far successful cygwin compile)

So - I've managed to compile Node.exe using Cygwin but not the preferred Mingw. I concur this isn't an ideal situation, building on Windows isn't the ideal. Nevertheless.

The error I see in Mingw, once I've followed all of the steps above, occurs when I try to `./configure --without-ssl`. The error message is:

```
Danjah@PC /c/cygwin/home/Danjah/node-v0.4.7/node
$ ./configure –without-ssl
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

I understand from step 3's URL, that I must take steps to provide the environment variables for both Python and Git - using help from the provided URL I managed to input the Python path var, but I don't think I have the Git path var right. Either way, in no install directories for Python, Cygwin or Mingw32 do I see the path specified in the error msg: "`/usr/bin/env`".

Googling didn't really bring much to the table in terms of env variables or Mingw32, best I got was: `PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`  where my install directory is at `C:\MingW\`.

The path I added to Windows environment vars for Python was:  `PythonPath=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk`  where Python 2.7 is installed in `C:\Python27\`.

I hate it when a file path stops you from doing things, as I suspect is the problem here. So please set me straight here - is it a file path problem I have or something else? And if its something else, please try and help me to get Node up and running... keen as to get experimenting.

I should probably also mention that I do also have a previously installed version of [Git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3) on my Windows XP SP3 machine, but had not previously had Cygwin, Mingw32 or Python installed, and I do not have IIS running as a service - my usual testing environment is a WAMP stack.

Comment: Which shell are you using for the compile? Typically, this would be either the Windows Command Console (cmd.exe), /bin/bash, /bin/tcsh or similar. The correct answer depends on this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses the PATH environment variable to locate programs that are invoked without a fully qualified file path, i.e. 'python' rather than 'C:\Python27\python'.

So you need to *add* python's home directory to the Windows PATH variable, *as well as* MinGW, git and anything else your script requires.

Also by setting the PATH variable explicitly in your shell session or script, you are overwriting its original contents (in the local context) which limits which programs your shell can find to only those available within the PATH which is usually a bad idea.

See http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml for details on modifying your PATH so you can always run your Python scripts from the command line.

Comment: I'm going to try that when I get home - basically I followed some online instructions for both Python and MinGW but had added them as separate name-value pair entries in the environment variables dialog. To answer your comment above - I am using MinGW as recommended on the 3rd link in my Q. I did have to actually use a different GIT bash to actually clone the repo, but after that I closed GIT down and switched back to MinGW to complete the compile process.